# DBMS - Cleaning dataset

Tags: database, bash, sed, data-cleaning

I am currently cleaning all the data I want to store in my database.
One of the problems I have is that certain attributes contains tabs. However, tab is also used as the delimiter, so the DBMS may erroneously think that one additional attribute exists in the line in question.

I have tried the following bash script:

```
cat titles.csv | sed -i 's/\\\t//g' > titles_copy.csv
```

but all I got was : "sed:no input files'
Why is that? I clearly specified the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the STDIN stream i.e. `/dev/stdin` as the input to inplace edit operation `sed -i`.

Use it like:

```
sed -i 's/\\\t//g' titles.csv
```

Or as you are saving the output to a different file, no need for `-i`:

```
sed 's/\\\t//g' titles.csv >titles_copy.csv
```